# Firebase REST API signInWithIdp and Apple SignIn Provider - MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE

Tags: react-native-firebase, apple-sign-in

I'm implementing Apple Sign In in a React Native App.

The sample I'm using works well within the Mobile App:
[Apple Sign In - React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#apple)

Just in case the link above changes, here is the code:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { appleAuth } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';

async function onAppleButtonPress() {
  // Start the sign-in request
  const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
    requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
    requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
  });

  // Ensure Apple returned a user identityToken
  if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
    throw 'Apple Sign-In failed - no identify token returned';
  }

  // Create a Firebase credential from the response
  const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
  const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(identityToken, nonce);

  // Sign the user in with the credential
  return auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);
}
```

In my backend Apps are only authorized to make calls if they use Firebase Access Tokens.

To get this to work, I am using the Google/Firebase REST API signInWithIdp. This works perfectly well for Twitter/Facebook/Google, but it doesn't for Apple.

What I/m doing is to use the Apple identityToken obtained here:

```
const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
```

And I make this call:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key={key}

BODY:
{
"postBody":"id_token={identityToken}&providerId=apple.com",
"requestUri":"http://localhost",
"returnSecureToken": true
}
```

but I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Due to the lack of documentation I'm blocked on this one. :(

Any suggestions on how to eliminate this error are very welcome. :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue somehow? I'm stuck here too.

Comment: Not yet...waiting for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) is the documentation to support 'Sign in with OAuth credential'. The examples it gives looks like this:

> id_token=[GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN]&providerId=[google.com]

You can actually add a `nonce` parameter as well (which isn't documented!), for example:

> id_token=ID_TOKEN&providerId=apple.com&nonce=NONCE

To figure this out, I had to use the SDK (I used iOS) and make the request. I used mitmproxy to read the network, and this is what it showed when putting in dummy data:

[image: Request]

Comment: I tried your approach and it didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @mmedina It works for me. Are you giving a valid `id_token`? I can't tell because on the line `"postBody":"id_token={identityToken}&providerId=apple.com",` I can't tell if that is using string interpolation or you are just giving `{identityToken}` (sorry I don't know much about the technologies you are using). Only things I can find for your error is that you may be reusing credentials

Comment: Initially I tried your approach and it didn't work, and I didn't understand why. 
After some reading I realised that apple IdTokens cannot be reused! That was the culprit, and then your request worked really well!

Comment: In my case after authentication, I'm using my credentials to authenticate on Firebase, then I was trying to reuse the same idToken to authenticate against an API.

Comment: @mmedina Great news that it now works! To help others in the future find the right answer, it may be useful to mark this answer as accepted, thank you :)

Comment: might be a silly question but does anyone know how what the difference is between the id_token and the key?

Comment: @mick1996 I’m not sure what you are referring to by “the key”